# filepath length errors in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Is there a maximum directory or char length for file paths in ArcMap 10.0? I spent hours trying to trouble-shoot an untyped crash in both ArcMap and Catalog when trying to reclassify and subsequently delete a large raster. Moving the files to a shorter directory seems to have fixed the issue, but now I am curious if there is a certain filepath length you cannot exceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using FileSystemWorkspace or Esri Grid format raster, there is a limitation in file name length and file path length. For raster name, maximum number of characters is 13 and for full path name, maximum number of character is 128. For more info, you can go through [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00590000001q000000).

Comment: This explains everything! I copied the raster from an already long directory onto my desktop. It is infuriating that ArcMap does not give a typed error for exceeding the filepath length.

Answer (score 3):

Usually path length limits in Windows are set to `MAX_PATH` (~260 characters). See [this page for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).